# Best way to "mvn link" a dependency?

Tags: java, maven

Let's say I have two projects on my machine, ProjectA and ProjectB; ProjectB uses ProjectA as a dependency.

I publish both of these packages separately as well. Now I want to develop locally, make changes to A but test is in B. How do I "link" ProjectA locally in ProjectB so that when I run ProjectB, it is using the local ProjectA and not the published package?

Comment: Not really clear, but are you using a multi-module Maven project?

Comment: You can `mvn install` a _snapshot_ version of project A in your local repository and then reference that snapshot version in project B.

Comment: @fluffy no, these are completely independent projects. I'm looking for something like `npm link` that easily allows you to use a local project as a dependency in another project of yours.

Comment: @Glains how does one do that?

Comment: In your `pom.xml` of project A, set the `version` to `x.y.z-SNAPHOT` and run `mvn install`, afterwards reference the snapshot version in project B by changing the version of A in dependencies. When releasing a version, remember to always remove the snapshot dependencies.

Comment: @Glains thank you! that was very helpful. Do you want to post it as a solution so I can mark it?

Comment: Yeah, then `mvn install` is what you need as suggested by @Glains. If it were a multi-module project, then `mvn compile` in the super-pom directory would work compiling all modules (if I'm not mistaken), that's a bit different than a single `mvn install` from a foreign Maven project.

Comment: @Kousha Sure, i have added some additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when referencing maven dependencies, you can use a fixed version number like `5.2.0` or a `SNAPHOT`-version like `5.2.0-SNAPSHOT` , which has the semantics as being *currently in development or work in progress*. Also, those versions are associated with an update timestamp in the repository to decide which `SNAPHOT` version is the newest.

Project A:

- Change the version in the root `.pom` to a `SNAPHOT`-version. (In multi-module projects, you can use [1] instead to not change every version manually.)
- Run `mvn install` your artifact to the local maven repository.

Project B:

- Reference the newly installed `SNAPSHOT`-version for project A in the dependencies section.
- Run `mvn compile` and the new version will be used.

Remember that releases sould not contain references to snaphot versions.
To automate this process (of changing back an forth between snapshot and release), you can use [2].

[1] [Versions Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)

- Use `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=your_new_version` to change a version.
- Then use `mvn versions:commit` or `mvn versions:rollback` respecively.

[2] [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin)